# using https with express io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https, socket.io

So I am new to express and io but I had a server running fine for webRTC but now there is a deprecated method in webRTC that only runs on https so I tried to create an https server but it starts and then immediately exits. I cannot figure out what is wrong and I do not get any errors. Also I am using an aws ec2 to run the express io server. Maybe someone can spot where in my syntax/implementation I am going wrong.

**Note I have been googling around for the past half hour and cannot figure it out**

Here is the code:

```
var connect = require('connect');
    var https = require('https');

    var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express.io');
var app = express();
//app.http().io();
var PORT = 443;

var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('../server.key'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('../server.crt')
};
app.https(options).io();
//var app = https.createServer(options, app1);

console.log('server started on port ' + PORT);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(PORT);

app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
      req.io.join(req.data.chat_room);
      req.io.join(req.data.signal_room);
      app.io.room(req.data).broadcast('announce', {
            message: 'New client in the ' + req.data + ' room.'
    })
})
```

**Update**

I am putting a bounty on this because I would like someone to provide me with a complete answer on setting up the server for production.

Comment: Well I changed the port number to 4000 and it worked so idk if there is a problem with my listening syntax or listening on port 443

Comment: `0 to 1023` is reserved   ports for OS service you can not use that ports that is reason behind this

Comment: Yeah but I am running on a live server so how can I deploy my webapp to port 443?

Comment: let  server allow to choose random port

Comment: use  this in production `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4730);`

Comment: It sound like the OS is rejecting the port access request, whether it gave you an error message or not. Look into the task mgr to see what app is assigned to the ports in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a rule for port 443 in a Security Group for your instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html might help.